# Simplify input value to search a page with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, search

I'm just new to Javascript and I have a little question that hopefully, someone can help me with.

I have this javascript code that works great, and I'm not sure if this is possible but I'd like to simplify the HTTPS so that this search script can be used across many different versions of the same project. Just now it will only work on "alphatest" which means we have to change the link for this script for "beta" and "test" I'd love to have the one code that'll work for all of them without having to always change the HTTPS part. I hope I'm making sense..

Thanks!

```
  search.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
if (event.keyCode == '13') {
  window.location = "https://documentation.five9.com/alphatest/Content/Search.htm?q=" + this.value;
}
```

});

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-environment-variables

Answer (score 0):

You can build a dynamic URL using window.location.pathname. This should remove the domain and protocol.

```
search.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
if (event.keyCode == '13') {
  window.location = window.location.pathname + "?q=" + this.value
 }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, it didn't work and there were not any errors which is great...I'm thinking it's maybe the system we are trying to publish from which is MadCap Central and their environment can be really fussy....